# Use personal lists of books to inform targeted advertising

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Then use the lists to help decide which books on Amazon to show adverts for, taking into account the tags on the given question and the tags on questions the user has answered or asked.

---

This need not be as complex as people seem to think, e.g. just find books that are listed most often by users “related” to a given tag and sometime choose a random one to show the advert for.

The chosen book only have to be interesting sometimes for this to be worth while, provided it is  not displacing paid for adverts.

Comment: Suggestion title originally described a feature that already exists (users can add lists of books or whatever else they want to their "bio box"). Adjusted to reflect actual suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use your public About Me section to put whatever you want in there?

Comment: Because that's not needlessly complex!

Answer (score 2):

A personal home page/blog is a great place to do it. There's a Website link in your profile for the exact same purpose.

<sub>Beside book list, you can add a mouse-pointer tracking script, and a javascript alert box that welcomes users when they come to your page :)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the marketing department at Amazon is working hard to only show books people want to buy. Why not leave them to it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very complex.... and the books associated with the *user* may have little to do with the specific *question*. Besides; which user? The OP? Many questions are asked by new / unregistered accounts, who are unlikely to have a list.

IMO, leave it just with the question text/tags. If you want to add your favorite books to your profile you can already do this, of course.